¿Cómo ajustar a la Izquierda el texto de la columna índice de una tabla creada con matplotlib de python?
Cree la tabla con el siguiente código, lo que hace que todas mis columnas se ajusten hacia la derecha (cellLoc='right')
tabla_plt = ax.table(cellText=data_for_table, colLabels=column_labels, loc='center',cellLoc='right')

(https://www.bing.com/images/blob?bcid=spt6LucGSOkG7w)
¿Cómo puedo hacer que sólo la columna del índice quede ajustada a la izquierda?

Que yo sepa no hay una forma directa de hacer esto sin crear la tabla manualmente, pero en principio cambiar la alineación del texto de cada celda de la columna una vez creada la tabla debería funcionar:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


column_labels = ('Indice', 'Columna A', 'Columna B')
data_for_table = (
    ("Fila 1", "aaaaa", "bbbbb"),
    ("Fila 2", "ccccc", "ddddd"),
    ("Fila 3", "eeeee", "fffff")
)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.axis('tight')
ax.axis('off')
tabla_plt = ax.table(
    cellText=data_for_table,
    colLabels=column_labels,
    loc='center',
    cellLoc='right'
    )

for i in range(1, len(data_for_table) + 1):
    tabla_plt[i, 0].set_text_props(ha="left")

plt.show()


Probado en matplotlib-3.8.4
